# contar registro baseado em variavel

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá

Estou tentando construir uma busca no registro Mysql por dois parâmetros; nome e datas.

Por exemplo, preciso fazer uma execução em Php onde informo o nome de quem cadastrou ( Caixa) e datas que ocorreu o cadastro( De  data x até data y).
 Até o momento consegui essa linha de código que me informa de maneira organizada tudo que tem na tabela. Porém em minhas pesquisa não encontrei nenhum comando nativo do mysql que filtra da forma que preciso.

Alguém pode me indicar o que devo fazer pra separar e exibir só os dados que preciso? Desde já muito obrigado.

```
<?php
 $caixa= $_POST['caixa'];
 $datade=$_POST['datade'];
 #muda o padrão de data é indespensavel para o mysql ler os dados
 $datade= date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$datade)));
 $dataate=$_POST['dataate'];
 #muda o padrão de data é indespensavel para o mysql ler os dados
 $dataate= date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$dataate)));

 $sql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT caixa,data COUNT(*) FROM clientes group by caixa");

 echo "$sql";
 ?>
```

Comment: `"SELECT caixa, data COUNT(*) FROM clientes where data >=".$datade." and data <=".$dataate."  group by caixa"` isso se você quiser incluir registros feitos também nas duas datas de referencia. Se quiser somente entre elas, remova o `=` da comparação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o BETWEEN do MySQL para pesquisar por um intervalo.

```
$sql= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT caixa, data, COUNT(*) FROM clientes WHERE caixa = '{$caixa}' AND data BETWEEN '{$datade}' AND '{$dataate}' GROUP BY caixa, data");
```